# bind a c++ class method (with parameter) to a ref class method

Tags: c++-cx

Can i bind a c++ class method with argument to a ref class method?

```
using Finish = std::function<void(bool status)>;
class Controller
{
public:
    Controller(Finish func);
private:
    Finish m_onFinish;
    bool m_isFinished = false;
}

Controller::Controller(Finish func)
    : m_onFinish(func)
{    
}    
Controller::Execute()
{
    ...
    m_isFinished = true;
    ...
    m_onFinish(m_isFinished)
    ...
}

public ref class MainPage sealed
{
    public :
        MainPage(); 
        void OnFinished(bool status);
    private:
    std::unique_ptr<Controller> m_controller;
}    
MainPage()
{
    auto finishCallBack = std::bind(&OnError, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    m_controller = std::make_unique<Controller>(finishCallBack);
}
```

I am getting below Error :

```
error C2664: 'Controller::Controller(const Controller &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl *)(bool),MainPage ^,const std::_Ph<1> &>' to 'Finish'
```

This usually works in with pure c++. But Looks like it doesn't work with ref class.

Please suggest.

Comment: Perhaps try using a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of `std::bind`?

Comment: did you try with argument?

Answer (score 0):

Argument based function doesn't work with `std::bind` for binding c++ class method with ref class method. Below work around worked for me:

In C++ class

```
using Finish = std::function<void(bool status)>;

std::vector<Finish> m_funcs;

void Executor()
{
    for(const auto& func : m_funcs)
    {
        // Trigger the function
        func(true);
    }
}

void Register(const std::vector<Finish>& funcs)
{
    m_funcs = funcs
}
```

Main Page (UWP ref class)

```
m_controller->Register({
            [=] { OnFinish(bool val); /*A method of this class that will be executed from the controller*/ }
});
```